# Express JS and CoinPayments: coudn't get the request body of IPN notification request

Tags: node.js, express, paypal-ipn, coinpayments-api

So here is my problem, I work with Express JS,  I am setting up payments with coinPayments, everything work npm coinpayments, however I couldn't get any body with the IPN

```
router.post(
  `/notify`,
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('ok');
    console.log('------------------------------ipn--------------------------------------');
    console.log('body', req.body);
    console.log('------------------------------ipn--------------------------------------');
    if (
      !req.get(`HMAC`) ||
      !req.body.ipn_mode ||
      req.body.ipn_mode !== `hmac` ||
      MERCHANT_ID !== req.body.merchant
    ) {
      return next(new Error(`Invalid request`));
    }

    let isValid;
    let error;

    try {
      isValid = verify(req.get(`HMAC`), IPN_SECRET, req.body);
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }

    if (error && error) {
      return next(error);
    }

    if (!isValid) {
      return next(new Error(`Hmac calculation does not match`));
    }

    return next();
  }
```

I always get an empty req.body

```
 ------------------------------ipn--------------------------------------
 body {}
 ------------------------------ipn--------------------------------------
Invalid request at router.post.txn_id.txn_id
```

Does anyone have an idea why , and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [coinpayment documentation](https://www.coinpayments.net/merchant-tools-ipn)

> It is implemented by making a standard HTTP POST
> (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) call over a https:// or http://
> URL to a script or CGI program on your server.

In your Express server, you may need to add the middleware to parse requests in urlencoded format:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: it works !! Thank you so much for your support and your explanation Đăng Khoa Đinh